# Powershell SendEmail command prompting for from and subject parameter

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I'm Preparing a batch file which contains a powershell command that will send email using SMTP. It's working properly and I'm able to send email but the issue is it's prompting for **From** and **Subject** parameter. How can I avoid the prompt?

This is my batch file script:

```
powershell.exe -command " & {Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer 10.10.10.101 -To testuse@domain.com; -From 'alerts@domain.com' -Subject 'Sql Server Agent Shut Down' -Body 'Sql Server Agent Shut Down now today';}"
```

Comment: Get rid of that semicolon after testuse@domain.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `;` from the `-To` address:

```
powershell.exe -command " & {Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer 10.10.10.101 -To 'testuse@domain.com' -From 'alerts@domain.com' -Subject 'Sql Server Agent Shut Down' -Body 'Sql Server Agent Shut Down now today'}"
```